# How to find matching values between the columns of two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, named `Child` and `Parent`. `Child` acts like a metadata table, and I need to validate the Data of `Parent` dataframe.

Child:

```
Cust_id     Description   Detail
1           Good          Regular
34          Excellent     Normal
45          Bulk          Buyer
```

Parent:

```
Name    Cust_id order   date    Payment
xyz     1       ice     01-02-2019  online
abc     45      bread   01-02-2019  offline
mno     56      Butter  01-02-2019  offline
pqr     67      cookies 01-02-2019  online
rst     34      Rice    01-02-2019  online
ert     1       egg     01-02-2019  online
```

I need to validate `Cust_id` present in the `Parent` dataframe or not?

I am selecting on all record `Cust_id` of `Parent` table using distinct, and using a loop to check if all data present in the `Parent` table, are present in the `Child` table or not.

How can this be accomplished without iteration, using pandas methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [pandas Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) the determine if `'Cust_id'` of `parent`, is in `'Cust_id'` of `'child'`.
- Use [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) on a list of unique `'Cust_id'` from 'child'.

  - [Indexing with isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin)
  - `child.Cust_id.unique()` creates an array of all the unique values in `'Cust_id'`

```py
import pandas as pd

child = pd.DataFrame({'Cust_id': [1, 34, 45], 'Description': ['Good', 'Excellent', 'Bulk'], 'Detail': ['Regular', 'Normal', 'Buyer']})

parent = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['xyz', 'abc', 'mno', 'pqr', 'rst', 'ert'], 'Cust_id': [1, 45, 56, 67, 34, 1], 'order': ['ice', 'bread', 'Butter', 'cookies', 'Rice', 'egg'],
                       'date': ['01-02-2019', '01-02-2019', '01-02-2019', '01-02-2019', '01-02-2019', '01-02-2019'], 'Payment': ['online', 'offline', 'offline', 'online', 'online', 'online']})

# mask using isin
mask = parent.Cust_id.isin(child.Cust_id.unique())

# return only the data from parent, where parent Cust_id isin child Cust_id
parent[mask]

# add a column to the parent dataframe
parent['in_child'] = mask

# display(parent)
  Name  Cust_id    order        date  Payment  in_child
0  xyz        1      ice  01-02-2019   online      True
1  abc       45    bread  01-02-2019  offline      True
2  mno       56   Butter  01-02-2019  offline     False
3  pqr       67  cookies  01-02-2019   online     False
4  rst       34     Rice  01-02-2019   online      True
5  ert        1      egg  01-02-2019   online      True
```

- [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) can be used in various ways as well.
- The following solution uses an `'outer'` merge with `indicator=True`

  - The `'_merge'` column indicates which dataframe the `'Cust_id'` is in.

    - `'left_only'` is the `parent` dataframe.
- `.merge` combines the information from both dataframes, and I'm not sure if that's the desired output.

```py
merged = parent.merge(child, on='Cust_id', how='outer', indicator=True)

# display(merged)
  Name  Cust_id    order        date  Payment Description   Detail     _merge
0  xyz        1      ice  01-02-2019   online        Good  Regular       both
1  ert        1      egg  01-02-2019   online        Good  Regular       both
2  abc       45    bread  01-02-2019  offline        Bulk    Buyer       both
3  mno       56   Butter  01-02-2019  offline         NaN      NaN  left_only
4  pqr       67  cookies  01-02-2019   online         NaN      NaN  left_only
5  rst       34     Rice  01-02-2019   online   Excellent   Normal       both
```